# In Keras, how to store all the layers weights of different models at the same place?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In the context of  [Neural Architecture Search](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-architecture-search-nas-the-future-of-deep-learning-c99356351136), I created a loop in which I create and train a different model at each iteration. Like this:

```
for i in range(100):

    ... creating different kind of layers each iter

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train)

    del model # I don't keep the model itself, I am training the Controller
```

In order to make my algorithm learn faster, I want to save the weights of layers that were already trained, and to **reuse** them in the next iterations (if ever the corresponding layers are created again).

I though I could do like this.

```
for i in range(100):

    ... creating different kind of layers each iter

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    model.load_weight("weights", by_name=True)

    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train)

    model.save_weight("weights")

    del model
```

But I think this code is problematic. Indeed, if at *iteration 1*, a layer called *name_1* is created, and if in the next iteration this layer is not instanciated in the model, then its weights will be **overwritten** when saving the weights at *iteration 2*, i.e, they will be non existing in *iteration 3*.

Also, I have this warning from TensorFlow that may indicates this problem

> WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph

Any idea ?

**[EDIT]**

Example of a layer created:

```
x = layers.Conv2D( 10, (2, 10), padding="same", activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[:-1], name="my_special_layer" ) (x)
```

So, if *my_special_layer* is created at iteration 1, but not at iteration 2, I still want to have access to it at iteration 3. Off course, I don't want to save a different file for each model created! (it would be too much files).

Comment: The **different kind of layers each iter**, does it mean your model's definition is different? If so, how would you like to transfer weight? otherwise, can you share your model definition (minimal)?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes the model at each iteration is a new model, composed with different layers EXCEPT for SOME layers that are the same (with same name)

Comment: By using `by_name=True`, what's the issue you've faced practically (rather than your assumption)?

Comment: 'by_name=True' is useful to retrieve the layers weights by the name of the layers, which is good, but I also want to retrieve layers from several previous timesteps that were not instanciated/created on the last time step.

Comment: Ok, I think the solution would be to use h5py, in order to create a global file that save all the layers weights. If someone shows a POC with this method, I will be happy to validate the answer, otherwise I will do it ^^